# Maxwell's equation in free space from wave equations of electric and magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

How to go from the wave equations of electric and magnetic field and $$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf E = 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad \ 0 = \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf B,
$$

to the remaining two Maxwell's equation in free space?

I am unable to do this, for a long time now. Please help. :) Is it even possible to do it?

The question arose from the following: 
[Are Wave equations equivalent to Maxwell equations in free space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465013/)

Comment: Can volts per square meter be equal to teslas per meter, even if both are zero?

Comment: You need the Lorentz force. Without or without any equation implying it, E and B are undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is impossible.

A simple counter-example is the fields
\begin{align}
\mathbf E(\mathbf r,t) & = E_0 \hat{\mathbf e}_x \cos(kz-\omega t)\\
\mathbf B(\mathbf r,t) & = 0,
\end{align}
i.e. a plane-wave electric field and a vanishing magnetic field. This satisfies both force-field wave equations as well as both transversality conditions, but it breaks both the Faraday-Lenz and the Ampere-Maxwell laws.

The core intuition that this counter-example captures is that the basis that you've laid out simply does not include enough information that relates the electric to the magnetic field (specifically: it doesn't provide any such information at all) for the curl equations to be reconstructed.