# How to extract all information regarding electric and magnetic fields from Maxwell's equations in free space?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Is it possible to obtain some set of equations in E and B that have decoupled E and B , but are **exactly equivalent** to Maxwell's equations in free space?

**Exactly equivalent** in the sense that the any solution to those decoupled equations is the solution to the coupled ones and any solution to coupled ones is solution to decoupled ones.

Comment: Here is a sufficient set of additional conditions to impose: \begin{align}\nabla \cdot \mathbf E & = 0  &&&  \nabla \cdot \mathbf B & = 0\\ \nabla \times \mathbf E & = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} &&& \nabla \times \mathbf B & = \epsilon_0\mu_0\frac{\partial\mathbf E}{\partial t}. \end{align}

Comment: Here E and B and coupled.. if i want them in decoupled form?? Wait i will change the question..

Comment: ... or, in other words, "what conditions to impose?" is an ill-formed and ultimately unanswerable question. This is because (i) the question does not establish any clear criterion for how your "extra conditions" should differ from the final product, i.e. from the Maxwell equations, and (ii) the question does not set any criterion for simplicity or interestingness. Without having both of those in place, it's meaningless to ask.

Comment: Is it meaningful now? @EmilioPisanty

Comment: To the extent that there is anything new here, it is just a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: There is no reason to expect to be able to understand electric and magnetic fields as uncoupled. They are two parts of a single unified electromagnetic field, $F_{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to obtain some set of equations in E and B that have decoupled E and B , but are exactly equivalent to maxwell's equations in free space?

**No**, for the same reasons as in [your previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465114/maxwells-equation-in-free-space-from-wave-equations-of-electric-and-magnetic-fi). The requirement that the prospective set of equations be equivalent to the Maxwell equations implies that it needs to be a homogeneous linear system, which means that the zero field must be a solution.

By any reasonable understanding of "decoupled", if your prospective equations are decoupled, then they must allow a nonzero electric field with a nontrivial time variation and a vanishing magnetic field. (If this is not allowed by your equations, then they're not decoupled.) But such a solution is inconsistent with the Maxwell equations.

Comment: (To which I suspect your reaction will be to keep trying to come up with ever more complicated ways to complicate a fundamentally-ill-posed question, and to dig yourself into a rabbit hole that's so deep that no one will be able to dig you out. That seems like a pretty pointless exercise to me.)

Comment: Thank you very much . You are very kind. Now i understand.

Comment: @KavitaJuneja Apologies for the short-fused patience.